# Qual é a diferença entre 401 Unauthorized e 403 Forbidden?

Tags: http, http-status

Ao desenhar uma aplicação, é comum eu ficar em dúvida quanto a qual código HTTP retornar quando um usuário não tem acesso a um determinado recurso: se é `401 Unauthorized` ou se é `403 Forbidden`.

Queria uma explicação clara quanto à diferença entre ambos.

Comment: +1 pela pergunta. Eu tenho a mesma dúvida :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## 401 Unauthorized

Ela ocorre quando o acesso ao recurso do servidor requer autenticação - através do cabeçalho `WWW-Authenticate` - e esta falha por algum motivo (falta de credencial ou credencial inválida). O cliente tentando conectar o servidor **pode** tentar uma nova requisição com um credencial mais apropriada. Se uma nova tentativa for feita pelo mesmo agente com as mesmas credenciais o servidor **deve** fornecer mais informações relevantes para o usuário entender o que está acontecendo.

A semântica a ser entendida aqui é que falta autenticação válida, só isto.

## 403 Forbidden

Ocorre quando o servidor recusa atender o pedido por causa de alguma regra que determina a negação do acesso. O cliente **não deve** tentar novamente mesmo com credenciais já que a negação não ocorreu por falha do cliente, nem tão pouco por algo que poderá ser resolvido no servidor por conta própria. O servidor **pode** dar maiores informações se a tentativa for feita com um método `HEAD`. Estas informações **devem** descrever a razão para a negação. Caso ele não deseje dar maiores informações então o código de erro de ser trocado pelo `404 Not Found`.

A semântica aqui é que não foi dada autorização de acesso independente do que o cliente forneça.

[Fonte](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-66).

Ainda que não esteja **estritamente correto** de acordo com a RFC, alguns servidores são configurados para só responder `404 Not Found` em qualquer deste casos. Isto segue o princípio da [obscuridade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46057/101).

Se considerar que a autenticação via HTTP caiu em desuso na maioria das aplicações; e que saber se o recurso não existe ou você não pode acessar, no fundo dá no mesmo; em uma abordagem pragmática faz sentido deixar de lado estes dois códigos de erro.

Claro que pode haver casos para usar a recomendação mas é preciso saber quando. O uso criativo e responsável dos códigos não é algo inerentemente ruim. [REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/101) é um caso onde se usa muito, e há discussões intermináveis sobe qual deve usar em cada caso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A meu ver é a resposta mais completa. Sanou minhas dúvidas :)

Comment: Respondi porque percebi que as outras faltavam alguma coisa :)

Comment: Sim, ficou uma boa resposta, apesar de ter respondido coisas técnicas que realmente não estavam na pergunta. Mas toda informação é bem-vinda :) e desta vez sem depreciar as demais respostas.

Comment: Eu não deprecio outras respostas, eu comento sobre respostas que se depreciam com erros existentes. Deixar passar erros existentes sem comentar nada é um prejuízo para toda a comunidade. Erros devem ser apontados, não jogados para baixo do tapete. Eu sei que muita gente acha que a preocupação deve ser com o indivíduo, eu acho que que a preocupação deve ser com a comunidade.

Comment: Concordo com você, infelizmente apesar de não ter depreciado neste momento você ainda procura distorcer um pouco as coisas, mas não irei entrar em discussão, apenas elogiei a boa resposta e a sua melhora ao se portar diante das demais respostas. :) Até logo.

Answer (score 19):

O Erro 401 se refere apenas quanto a autenticação, mas não trata autorização.

O Erro 401 será retornado quando o sistema não conseguir identificar o usuário, enquanto que o erro 403 quando o sistema conseguir identificar o usuário, porém detectar que ele não tem permissão para aquele conteúdo.

Comment: simples e direto ao ponto!

Answer (score 16):

### [401 Unauthorized](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2)

É semelhante ao `403 Forbidden`, mas usamos especificamente quando uma autenticação é necessária e ela falha ou não é feita tal autenticação. É usado geralmente com `HTTP Basic Authentication`

### [403 Forbidden](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4)

Pode ser uma área restrita, o pedido é considerado valido, porém o servidor recusa-se a respondê-lo. Diferente do `401 Unauthorized` que necessitará de uma autenticação.

Answer (score 5):

Existem dois conceitos importantes que explico abaixo. Mas, como o nome do erro 401 é "não autorizado", quando na verdade deveria ser "não autenticado", ocorre esse tipo de confusão.

#### Autenticação

Autenticação é o processo que visa identificar *quem* é o usuário. Em outras palavras, se o usuário está "logado" ele está autenticado.

#### Autorização

Autorização é o processo que visa identificar se um usuário **tem permissão** de realizar uma operação. Naturalmente, ela depende da autenticação pois não há como saber se um usuário pode fazer algo sem saber quem é esse usuário (sem ele estar logado).

#### 401 - Unauthorized

Esse erro só indica se o usuário está ou não autenticado, embora o nome do erro seja "não autorizado", o que confunde bastante. Então, esqueça o nome pois o nome correto deveria ser "401 - Unauthenticated (Não autenticado)".

#### 403 - Forbidden

Esse sim indica que o servidor sabe quem é o usuário (ou seja, ele está logado), porém o usuário não tem permissão de acessar o recurso solicitado (por isso o nome Forbidden (Proibido)).

Em suma, o problema todo da confusão ocorre devido ao nome inapropriado do erro 401!

Fonte: [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses)