# Como funciona os códigos de status de respostas HTTP?

Tags: http, http-status

Estou redirecionando um usuário para a rota root caso ele não passe por uma condição e o framework slim pede um status http para o redirecionamento.

Com isto eu não compreendi exatamente como funciona este processo, observei que o status 301 me indica um estado de movido e atualiza as requisições futuras para a nova página.

Como funciona os status HTTP e o que seriam as requisições citadas acima

Trecho do meu código:

```
$app->post('/contact', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    if (condição) {
        //code
    } else {
        return $response->withRedirect('/', 301);
    }
}
```

Comment: É só uma indicação para o cliente que está consumindo sua aplicação. Retornar um 301 significa que você mudou a URL, que o recurso que ele está acessando está acessível em outra URL; assim, ele pode, nas próximas requisições, já fazer a requisição na URL correta. O 302, que é o que mais se adequa a situação, mas não perfeitamente, indica ao cliente que o recurso que ele está acessando está temporariamente em outra URL e que ele deve continuar requisitando nessa mesma futuramente (estou no celular, não consigo fazer uma resposta completa).

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pra entender o que é o código de status, primeiro precisa saber o que é o HTTP:

Uma aplicação geralmente tem duas partes, uma que roda no lado do cliente (browser, app nativo, etc) e uma que roda no lado do servidor. No caso da web, a primeira só pode ser HTML, CSS e JS, já a outra pode ser JS, Python, C#, Java entre diversas outras, no seu caso, é o PHP

O HTTP é, resumidamente, o formato de comunicação entre o teu PHP (ou qualquer outra coisa) com seu cliente. Ele é formado por um par de requição e resposta, ou seja, tem uma estrutura que é usada para o seu cliente pedir algo para o servidor (chamada requisição, ou *request*, em inglês) e é seguida por outra estrutura que serve para o servidor entregar o que foi pedido (chamada resposta, ou *response*, em inglês). Ambas são semelhantes:

Requisição

```
POST /contact_form.php HTTP/1.1
Host: developer.mozilla.org
Content-Length: 64
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name=Joe%20User&request=Send%20me%20one%20of%20your%20catalogue
```

Resposta

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 55743
Content-Language: en-US

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>A simple webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Simple HTML5 webpage</h1>
  <p>Hello, world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

A primeira linha da **requisição** informa, na sequencia:

- Método: os básicos são GET, POST, PUT e DELETE ([entenda melhor aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49322))
- URL: o caminho para onde a requisição será enviada
- A versão do HTTP, geralmente é 1.1 mas [já existe a 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167014)

A primeira linha da **resposta** informa, na sequencia:

- Versão do HTTP, é a mesma coisa da requisição
- Código da resposta, vou explicar depois, afinal é principal dúvida
- Descrição do código, basicamente é uma palavra ou expressão que acompanha o código, cada código tem a sua descrição

A partir daí (sgunda linha em diante) é igual tanto nas requisições como nas respostas

- Os cabeçalhos, ou *headers*, em inglês. Tem o formato `Nome-Do-Cabeçalho: Valor`, são informações úteis que podem ser usadas pelo receptor (servidor ou cliente) para decidir se e como tratar aquele dado, por exemplo, tipo de conteúdo (`Content-Type`), cache (`Cache-Control`, `Expires`, ...), língua do conteúdo (`Accept-Language` e `Content-Language`), autenticação (`Authorization`), entre vários outros
- Uma linha em branco, ela divide os cabeçalhos da próxima e última parte...
- O corpo, ou *body*, em inglês, é o conteúdo em si, pode estar em diversos formatos (geralmente especificado no cabeçalho). Na requisição costuma conter dados para ler (`SELECT * FROM ...`) ou escrever (`INSERT INTO ...` ou `UPDATE ... SET ...` ou `DELETE FROM ...`) algo no lado do servidor. Na resposta contém os dados que foram requisitados, pode ser um JSON, XML, HTML, PDF, CSV ou qualquer outra coisa

Você pode olhar a [wiki](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/http/info) da tag ou procurar perguntas/respostas com [http](/questions/tagged/http)

---

Agora que você sabe, pelo menos eu espero que saiba, o que é o HTTP, vamos a pergunta, *"Como funciona os códigos de status de respostas HTTP?"*

Bom, se você pediu algo para seu servidor podemos concordar que a resposta pode variar, por exemplo, se alguém está tentando mudar a senha de usuário, porém não está logado, a resposta deve ser um erro, já se a pessoa estiver devidamente autenticada, então deve aprarecer uma mensagem de sucesso. O status serve pra isso, dizer qual é o tipo de resposta. Ele é divido em *ranges* (não sei bem como poderia traduzir, talvez classes ou divisões):

- **1xx**: todas os status que começam com 1 são do tipo informativos (acredito que é muito pouco usada, se já usei realmente não lembro)
- **2xx**: todas os status que começam com 2 são do tipo sucesso, a requisição não tinha nenhum erro e o servidor conseguiu processar
- **3xx**: todas os status que começam com 3 são do tipo redirecionamento, como no 2xx, tudo ok, porém o conteúdo com a resposta está em outro lugar
- **4xx**: todas os status que começam com 4 são do tipo erro do lado cliente, a requisição possui algum problema e o servidor não conseguiu processar
- **5xx**: todas os status que começam com 5 são do tipo erro do lado servidor, a requisição está correta, porém o servidor não conseguiu processar devido a algum problema

Para entender como funciona o *range* 1xx, de uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/384220), as requisições e respostas funcinam de forma um pouco diferente

Para o 2xx vou dar dois:

- `200 Ok` é a resposta típica quando está tudo certo, requisição correta e servidor conseguiu responder
- `201 Created` é a resposta não tão usada, significa que tudo está ok, como na anterior, mas também que o recurso (algo qualquer) foi criado

O 3xx, que é o foco da sua pergunta, vou colocar todos, porém copiadas da [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Mensagens_de_redirecionamento):

- `300 Multiple Choice`: a requisição tem mais de uma resposta possível. User-agent ou o user deve escolher uma delas. Não há maneira padrão para escolher uma das respostas.
- `301 Moved Permanently`: esse código de resposta significa que a URI do recurso requerido mudou. Provavelmente, a nova URI será especificada na resposta.
- `302 Found`: esse código de resposta significa que a URI do recurso requerido foi mudada temporariamente. Novas mudanças na URI poderão ser feitas no futuro. Portanto, a mesma URI deve ser usada pelo cliente em requisições futuras.
- `303 See Other`: o servidor manda essa resposta para instruir ao cliente buscar o recurso requisitado em outra URI com uma requisição GET.
- `304 Not Modified`: essa resposta é usada para questões de cache. Diz ao cliente que a resposta não foi modificada. Portanto, o cliente pode usar a mesma versão em cache da resposta.
- `305 Use Proxy`: foi definida em uma versão anterior da especificação HTTP para indicar que uma resposta deve ser acessada por um proxy. Foi depreciada por questões de segurança em respeito a configuração em banda de um proxy.
- `306 unused`: esse código de resposta não é mais utilizado, encontra-se reservado. Foi usado numa versão anterior da especificação HTTP 1.1.
- `307 Temporary Redirect`: o servidor mandou essa resposta direcionando o cliente a buscar o recurso requisitado em outra URI com o mesmo método que foi utilizado na requisição original. Tem a mesma semântica do código 302 Found, com a exceção de que o user-agent não deve mudar o método HTTP utilizado: se um POST foi utilizado na primeira requisição, um POST deve ser utilizado na segunda.
- `308 Permanent Redirect`: esse código significa que o recurso agora está permanentemente localizado em outra URI, especificada pelo cabeçalho de resposta Location. Tem a mesma semântica do código de resposta HTTP 301 Moved Permanently  com a exceção de que o user-agent não deve mudar o método HTTP utilizado: se um POST foi utilizado na primeira requisição, um POST deve ser utilizado na segunda.

No 4xx vou colocar dois muito comuns e deixo um link para outra pergunta explicando outros dois e suas difetenças ([`401 Unauthorized` vs `403 Forbidden`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50209/)):

- `400 Bad Request` significa que a requisição contém algum erro, pode ser um cadastro faltando preencher o nome, o CPF ser inválido (faltou um número, por exemplo), ou alguma outra coisa que impeça o processamento do servidor porque o cliente enviou algo errado
- `404 Not Found` significa que o recurso (algo qualquer) que o cliente buscou não existe, por exemplo, se essa pergunta for excluída e eu tentar acessa-lá, essa será a resposta

Por último, mas não menos importante, o 5xx:

- `503 Service Unavailable` acontece, geralmente, quando o servidor está em manutenção ou sobrecarregado e, portanto, o serviço está indiponível
- `505 HTTP Version Not Supported` será a resposta se eu fizer uma requisição usando o HTTP2 para um servidor que suporta apenas a 1.1

As respostas 400 e 500 são mais amplas, algum erro que ocoreu ou do cliente ou do servidor, podendo ter status mais específicos do problema

[Lista completa de status de resposta HTTP (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

[Lista completa de status de resposta HTTP (Wikipedia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP)

[Documentação oficial original (rfc2068)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-6.1)

[Link para rfc mais atual de cada status](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml)

Comment: Muito obrigado, dei uma olhada no meu projeto de estudo pelo Dev e consegui ver esses status, agora consigo entender melhor qual o tipo de resposta minhas requisições trazem. Vou até salvar sua explicação.

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada nos links dos métodos HTTP, bem útil, também pode dar uma olhada em outras perguntas do HTTP

Comment: @JohnCovv  as fontes que eu postei em minha resposta contém tudo isto o qual está nesta resposta copiada e colada.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS algum problema? Como gosto do assunto, quis dar uma resposta mais completa e com minhas palavras, a única parte que copiei e colei foi as explicações dos status 3xx, e mencionei isso

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP**

> O ***Hypertext Transfer Protocol***, sigla **HTTP** **(em português Protocolo de Transferência de Hipertexto)** é um **protocolo de comunicação (na camada de aplicação segundo o Modelo OSI)** utilizado para sistemas de informação de hipermídia, distribuídos e colaborativos. Ele é a base para a comunicação de dados da **World Wide Web (WWW)**.
>
> [FONTE](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

**Hipertexto**

> É o **texto estruturado** que utiliza **ligações lógicas (hiperlinks)** entre nós contendo texto. O **HTTP** é o **protocolo** para a **troca ou transferência de hipertexto**.
>
> [FONTE](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

**STATUS HTTP**

> Os **códigos de status das respostas HTTP** indicam se uma **requisição HTTP** foi **corretamente concluída**. As **respostas** são agrupadas em **cinco (5) classes: respostas de informação, respostas de sucesso, redirecionamentos, erros do cliente e erros do servidor.**
>
> [FONTE](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) - **ACESSE PARA DESCOBRIR OS CÓDIGOS DE STATUS DE RESPOSTAS HTTP E PARA QUE SERVEM**