# Quando e por que usar os status do range 1xx?

Tags: http, http-status

O range 1xx dos códigos de status de resposta HTTP são informativos, a descrição da [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP#1xx_Informativa), traduzido da [rfc2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-10.1):

*"Solicitação recebida, dando continuidade ao processo. Essa classe de códigos de status indica uma resposta provisória, constituída apenas do Status-Line e cabeçalhos opcionais, e é encerrado por uma linha vazia. Desde a versão HTTP/1.0 não são definidios todos os códigos de status 1xx, os servidores não devem enviar uma resposta 1xx para um cliente HTTP/1.0, exceto sob condições experimentais."*

O que quer dizer *"Desde a versão HTTP/1.0 não são definidios todos os códigos de status 1xx"*? Significa que está obsoleto? Não fico muito claro pra mim.

Qual é (ou era) a utilidades desses status? Poderia exemplificar com alguns casos de uso?

Quais os status oficiais? Na lista da Wikipedia consta 100, 101, 102 e 122. Já na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Respostas_informativas) apenas o 100, 101 e 102. No site da [Iana](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) possui 100, 101, 102 e 103

Comment: Acho que fiquei devendo o resto da resposta hahaha oops

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sem problemas, sua resposta, assim como está, já merece uma recompensa

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]

## Status 1xx estão obsoletos?

**Não**, **há um erro de tradução no trecho que citou da Wikipedia**.

O trecho original é:

> *Since HTTP/1.0 did not define any 1xx
> status codes, servers MUST NOT send a 1xx response to an HTTP/1.0
> client except under experimental conditions.*

Em que o termo "*since*" foi traduzido como "desde o", porém, neste contexto, seria melhor traduzido como "visto que", "como o" ou algo do gênero, isto é, locução subordinativa, daquilo que expressa a causa.

Uma melhor tradução seria:

> Visto que o HTTP/1.0 não define os códigos de status 1xx, servidores NÃO DEVEM enviar uma resposta 1xx para um cliente HTTP/1.0 exceto se sob condições experimentais.

Ou seja, isso não significa que o código de status 1xx está obsoleto, mas pelo contrário, que foi começado a utilizar a partir da HTTP/1.1.

## Qual a finalidade destas respostas?

Permitir o cliente que envie cabeçalhos e corpo da requisição separadamente. Isso porque, em algumas situações, o servidor será capaz de determinar se aceitará uma requisição ou não apenas com as informações de cabeçalho. Em casos que o corpo da requisição é muito grande haveria uma perda desnecessária de recurso ao enviá-lo para o servidor e ter a requisição negada. Dois principais recursos que seriam impactados diretamente por isso seriam o tempo de resposta, que por trafegar mais informações é esperado que leve mais tempo para entregar a mensagem, e o consumo de banda tanto do cliente quanto do servidor, por transmitir dados que não serão utilizados.

Uma situação bastante comum que tiraria proveito destas respostas são os envios de arquivo ao servidor. É comum o servidor ou aplicação terem validações quanto ao tipo (mimetype) do arquivo e do seu tamanho. Duas informações que já estariam presentes no cabeçalho da requisição, então o servidor poderia recusá-la sem ao menos receber, de fato, o arquivo.

Imagine as duas aplicações (browser e servidor) conversando:

- Browser: Bom dia, servidor, gostaria de lhe enviar um arquivo;
- Browser: Ele é um arquivo de vídeo, formato MKV;
- Browser: Ele possui 1.21 GB de tamanho;
- Browser: Por favor, confirme se eu posso enviá-lo;
- Servidor: Olá, browser, não envie, eu só aceito arquivos PDF com menos de 5 MB;

Neste caso, o browser nem precisou ter que enviar 1.21 GB de dados a toa (imagina enviar isso pela 4G), somente para saber que o servidor iria recusar a requisição. Em um caso válido aconteceria algo bastante semelhante:

- Browser: Bom dia, servidor, gostaria de lhe enviar um arquivo;
- Browser: Ele é um arquivo formato PDF;
- Browser: Ele possui 1.21 MB de tamanho;
- Browser: Por favor, confirme se eu posso enviá-lo;
- Servidor: Olá, browser, parece tudo ok, continue;
- Browser: Obrigado, aqui está o arquivo...

Ou seja, se com as informações presentes nos cabeçalhos não for suficiente para recusar a requisição, será retornado ao cliente para que ele continue e envie o corpo da mesma. Note que isso não é uma garantia de sucesso, pois os dados enviados pelo corpo podem estar corrompidos, serem de outro arquivo, etc.

### Quebrando expectativas

Se reparar nos diálogos acima nos dois casos o browser pediu a confirmação do servidor para continuar com a requisição. Por padrão o HTTP não funciona assim, então é preciso informar explicitamente quando o cliente irá esperar pela confirmação. Para tal, gera-se uma expectativa no cliente, que é enviada ao servidor através do cabeçalho `Expect`, informando qual é a expectativa.

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 1210000
Expect: 100-Continue
...
```

Ao informar `100-Continue` no cabeçalho `Expect` o cliente está informando para o servidor que aguardará a confirmação do mesmo para continuar o processo. Se o servidor autorizar a requisição, ele deve responder com `100 Continue`, mas se recusar, responderá com `417 Expectation Failed`.

[image]

## Considerações sobre servidores e proxies

Quando um servidor recebe uma requisição:

- Ao receber uma requisição que inclui o cabeçalho `Expect: 100-Continue`, o servidor DEVE responder com o status `100 Continue` e continuar fazendo a leitura do fluxo de entrada de dados ou enviar uma resposta final, negando a requisição. O servidor NÃO DEVE esperar pelo corpo de uma requisição ANTES de enviar a resposta `100 Continue`. Ao enviar uma resposta final rejeitando a requisição, a conexão com o cliente PODE ser fechada ou PODE continuar aberta, descartando qualquer dado que chegar da requisição rejeitada.
- O servidor NÃO DEVE enviar a resposta `100 Continue` se a requisição do cliente não possuir o cabeçalho `Expect: 100-Continue` e NÃO DEVE enviá-la também caso o cliente esteja utilizando HTTP/1.0, como já citado. Por questões de compatibilidade com a RFC 2068, o servidor PODE responder com `100 Continue` uma requisição que não possua o cabeçalho `Expect` que seja dos métodos `PUT` ou `POST`, exclusivamente na versão HTTP/1.1.
- O servidor PODE omitir a resposta `100 Continue` quando já tiver recebido todo o corpo da requisição previamente.
- O servidor DEVE enviar uma resposta final após receber e processar o corpo da requisição.

Quando a requisição é tratada por um proxy:

- Se um proxy receber uma requisição que inclui o cabeçalho `Expect` com o valor `100-Continue`, e o proxy souber que a próxima entidade trabalha com HTTP/1.1 ou superior, ou não conhecer a versão do HTTP que esta entidade aceita, o proxy DEVE encaminhar a mensagem incluindo o cabeçalho `Expect`.
- Se o proxy, nas mesmas condições da anterior, souber que a próxima entidade opera apenas com HTTP/1.0, o proxy NÃO DEVE encaminhar a mensagem, ao invés disso já deve responder o cliente com `417 Expectation Failed`.
- Proxy DEVE manter cacheada a versão que a próxima entidade utiliza para ser possível as duas verificações anteriores.
- O proxy NÃO DEVE encaminhar ao cliente qualquer resposta `100 Continue` que eventualmente receber caso a requisição original do cliente foi por HTTP/1.0.

## E como o servidor lida com isso?

Devo começar dizendo que isso depende do servidor. Não encontrei informações oficiais de como o Apache e Nginx (nunca trabalhei com outros além desses) lidam com o cabeçalho `Expect`, se alguém conhecer alguma documentação confiável por favor compartilhe nos comentários ou em outra resposta.

#### Ciclo de vida de uma requisição sem `Expect`

Primeiro, analisaremos o ciclo de vida de uma requisição "normal":

```
Cliente                              Servidor                              Aplicação
 ->█                                    |                                      |
   █- Cabeçalhos da Requisição -------->█                                      |
   █                                    █                                      |
   █- Corpo da Requisição ------------->█                                      |
   |                                    █                                      |
   |                                    █- Requisição Completa --------------->█
   |                                    |                                      █-[Processamento]
   |                                    █<----------------- Resposta Completa -█
   |                                    █                                      |
   █<---------- Cabeçalhos da Resposta -█                                      |
   █                                    █                                      |
   █<--------------- Corpo da Resposta -█                                      |
 <-█                                    |                                      |
```

Neste caso, temos:

1. O cliente envia ao servidor os cabeçalhos da requisição;
2. O cliente envia ao servidor o corpo da requisição;
3. O servidor executa a aplicação fornecendo uma API para a mesma acessar as informações da requisição;
4. A aplicação é executada gerando uma resposta que é enviada ao servidor;
5. O servidor envia ao cliente os cabeçalhos da resposta;
6. O servidor envia ao cliente o corpo da resposta;

Como comentado, nesta configuração o cliente deverá enviar a requisição completa para o servidor, que a analisará e servirá a aplicação, sendo esta última responsável por definir se a requisição será processada ou não. Em muitos casos essa decisão pode ser tomada somente com base nos cabeçalhos da requisição e é justamente isso que o cabeçalho `Expect` busca contornar.

#### Ciclo de vida de uma requisição com `Expect`

Quando a requisição possui `Expect` é gerada a possibilidade de ação por parte do servidor se irá recusar ou não a requisição apenas com base nos cabeçalhos.

```
Cliente                              Servidor                              Aplicação
 ->█                                    |                                      |
   █- Cabeçalhos da Requisição -------->█                                      |
   |                                    █-[Validação]                          |
   █<------------- Resposta 100 ou 417 -█                                      |
   █                                    |                                      |
 <-█-[Erro se 417]                      |                                      |
   █                                    |                                      |
   █- Corpo da Requisição ------------->█                                      |
   |                                    █                                      |
   |                                    █- Requisição Completa --------------->█
   |                                    |                                      █-[Processamento]
   |                                    █<----------------- Resposta Completa -█
   |                                    █                                      |
   █<---------- Cabeçalhos da Resposta -█                                      |
   █                                    █                                      |
   █<--------------- Corpo da Resposta -█                                      |
 <-█                                    |                                      |
```

Neste caso, temos:

1. O cliente envia ao servidor os cabeçalhos da requisição;
2. O servidor faz uma validação prévia dos cabeçalhos e define se aceita (100) ou reprova (417) a requisição;
3. Quando servidor retorna 417 o ciclo se encerra retornando o erro ao cliente;
4. Quando servidor retorna 100 o cliente prossegue enviando ao servidor o corpo da requisição;
5. O servidor executa a aplicação fornecendo uma API para a mesma acessar as informações da requisição;
6. A aplicação é executada gerando uma resposta que é enviada ao servidor;
7. O servidor envia ao cliente os cabeçalhos da resposta;
8. O servidor envia ao cliente o corpo da resposta;

Os passos 2, 3 e 4 são o que diferem esta configuração da anterior justamente no momento em que é dada a possibilidade ao servidor de aceitar o recusar a requisição somente com base nos cabeçalhos. Fora isso, podemos notar algumas peculiaridades que são de extrema importância quando é feita a implementação:

- O cliente, ao enviar uma requisição possuindo o cabeçalho `Expect`, deve ser capaz de receber uma resposta intermediária (100 ou 417) do servidor antes de efetivamente enviar o corpo da requisição;
- O cliente deve definir como lidará com as ocasiões que o servidor não enviar a resposta intermediária (100 ou 417); nesses casos o cliente pode (1) assumir que a requisição foi falha e abortar ou (2) enviar o corpo da requisição mesmo assim e verificar qual será a resposta final do servidor. A opção (2) costuma ser mais comum por ser naturalmente compatível com servidores que não tratam o cabeçalho `Expect`. Neste caso, o ciclo de vida da requisição é idêntica ao ciclo da requisição que não possui `Expect`;
- O servidor deve ser capaz de receber o corpo da requisição após enviar ao cliente a resposta intermediária (100 ou 417);
- O servidor deve ser capaz de lidar com as situações em que o cliente não enviará o corpo da requisição após a resposta intermediária, possivelmente abortando a conexão (*timeout*);
- O servidor deve ser capaz de lidar com clientes que enviam o corpo da requisição mesmo antes de receber a resposta intermediária - em casos do cliente não ter suporte ao cabeçalho `Expect`, o servidor deve omitir a resposta intermediária (100 ou 417) e processar a requisição normalmente; o ciclo de vida da requisição fica idêntica ao da requisição que não possui `Expect`;

Nesta configuração você fica, de certa forma, limitado a fazer a validação exclusivamente no servidor, ou seja, a validação que definirá se aceitará uma requisição ou não será feito com base nas configurações do servidor ou variáveis de ambiente. Há ainda a possibilidade de transferir essa validação para a aplicação (lembre-se que aqui estamos falando em implementar, do zero, um servidor web e não estamos presos à configurações de servidores comerciais).

#### Ciclo de vida de uma requisição com `Expect` validada pela aplicação

O ciclo de vida de uma requisição que seria previamente validada pela aplicação seria:

```
Cliente                              Servidor                              Aplicação
 ->█                                    |                                      |
   █- Cabeçalhos da Requisição -------->█                                      |
   |                                    █- Cabeçalhos da Requisição ---------->█
   |                                    |                                      █-[Validação]
   |                                    █<--------------- Resposta 100 ou 417 -█
   █<------------- Resposta 100 ou 417 -█                                      |
   █                                    |                                      |
 <-█-[Erro se 417]                      |                                      |
   █                                    |                                      |
   █- Corpo da Requisição ------------->█                                      |
   |                                    █                                      |
   |                                    █- Requisição Completa --------------->█
   |                                    |                                      █-[Processamento]
   |                                    █<----------------- Resposta Completa -█
   |                                    █                                      |
   █<---------- Cabeçalhos da Resposta -█                                      |
   █                                    █                                      |
   █<--------------- Corpo da Resposta -█                                      |
 <-█                                    |                                      |
```

Neste caso temos basicamente o mesmo ciclo de vida do anterior, onde o servidor que decidia se iria aceitar ou não a requisição, mas agora essa responsabilidade é transmitida para a própria aplicação deixando a arquitetura consideravelmente mais versátil que as outras configurações. Porém, para ser possível a própria aplicação deve suportar fazer a execução apenas com os cabeçalhos da requisição, o que faz com que a aplicação não seja compatível com servidores sem suporte ao `Expect`, onde a requisição seria entregue de forma completa de uma vez.

## Implementação (Em Python ♥)

Para que tudo isso seja possível, teremos que trabalhar a nível de *socket*, onde temos controle da comunicação entre as partes - isso tanto no cliente quanto no servidor. Desta forma, uma requisição feita através de um navegador foge do nosso controle e se o mesmo utilizará `Expect` ou não dependerá exclusivamente da equipe de desenvolvimento quando lidar com a conexão entre navegador/servidor. Um cliente bastante conhecido que possui suporte ao `Expect` é o cURL quando definida a propriedade `--expect100-timeout <seconds>` (na verdade [o cURL utiliza o `Expect` por padrão](https://gms.tf/when-curl-sends-100-continue.html) quando é uma requisição PUT ou uma requisição POST com mais de 1024 bytes de tamanho).

Para efeitos de demonstração, será implementado um servidor não inteiramente funcional em Python utilizando a biblioteca [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) devida à facilidade de implementação. Será considerado que o servidor responderá com um eco do corpo da requisição como corpo da resposta quando o corpo da requisição não exceder 42 bytes.

**Exemplo de requisição enviando menos de 42 bytes**

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> Content-Type: text/plain
> Content-Length: 35
> Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

> Um texto com menos de 42 caracteres

< HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 35

< Um texto com menos de 42 caracteres
```

**Exemplo de requisição enviando mais de 42 bytes**

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> Content-Type: text/plain
> Content-Length: 45
> Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed
< Content-Length: 37

< Nao e permitido mais de 42 caracteres

X Ja este texto tem muito mais de 42 caracteres
```

## Code time, baby!

> Código escrito em Python 3.7, funcionaria em 3.6 com pequenas adaptações.

```py
import asyncio
from typing import Coroutine


async def echo_server(
    reader: asyncio.StreamReader, 
    writer: asyncio.StreamWriter
) -> Coroutine:

    # Read the status line of the request
    status_line: bytes = await reader.readline()
    method, resource, version = status_line.decode('ascii').split()

    # Read the request headers
    headers: list = []
    has_expect_header: bool = False
    content_length: int = 0

    while True:
        header_line: bytes = await reader.readline()

        # End of headers
        if not header_line.strip():
            break

        header_name: str
        header_value: str

        header_name, header_value = header_line.decode('ascii').split(':', 1)
        headers.append((header_name.strip(), header_value.strip()))

        if header_name.strip().lower() == 'expect':
            has_expect_header = True
        elif header_name.strip().lower() == 'content-length':
            content_length = int(header_value)

    # Has the Expect header?
    if has_expect_header:

        # Validation
        if content_length > 42:
            writer.write(b'HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed\n')
            writer.write(b'Content-Length: 37\n\n')
            writer.write(b'Nao e permitido mais de 42 caracteres')
            await writer.drain()
            writer.close()
            return

        writer.write(b'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\n\n')
    
    # Read the request body
    body: bytes = await reader.read(content_length)

    # Send the echo response
    writer.write(b'HTTP/1.1 200 Ok\n')
    writer.write(f'Content-Length: {content_length}\n'.encode('ascii'))
    writer.write(b'Content-Type: text/plain\n\n')

    writer.write(body)
    await writer.drain()
    writer.close()

async def main(host, port):
    server = await asyncio.start_server(echo_server, host, port)
    await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main('127.0.0.1', 5000))
```

O código inicia um servidor em 127.0.0.1:5000 recebendo requisições HTTP. Se possuir o cabeçalho `Expect` o servidor fará a validação de `Content-Length`; se for menor ou igual a 42 (limite estipulado para o exemplo), a resposta 100 Continue será enviada permitindo que o cliente envie o corpo da requisição; se `Content-Length` superar o valor 42 a resposta 417 Expectation Failed é retornada encerrando a comunicação.

#### Iniciando o servidor

Ao executar o *script*, podemos utilizar o cURL como cliente para a validação.

```
$ python main.py
```

#### Requisição com `Expect` válida:

```
$ curl -v -H "Expect: 100-continue" -d "Um texto com menos de 42 caracteres" 127.0.0.1:5000

* Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1:5000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Length: 35
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
< Content-Length: 35
< Content-Type: text/plain
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
Um texto com menos de 42 caracteres
```

Veja que o cURL envia os cabeçalhos, o servidor responde com 100 Continue, o cURL exibe a mensagem de log *We are completely uploaded and fine*, envia o corpo da requisição e, por fim, recebe a resposta final, 200, do servidor com o eco da requisição.

> **Imagem 1**: Requisição válida feita manualmente a partir do `telnet 127.0.0.1 5000` enviando o cabeçalho `Expect` a um servidor configurado para receber no máximo 5 bytes

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Requisição com `Expect` inválida:

```
$ curl -v -H "Expect: 100-continue" -d "Ja este texto tem muito mais de 42 caracteres" 127.0.0.1:5000

* Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1:5000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Length: 45
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
< HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed
< Content-Length: 37
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
* Closing connection 0
Nao e permitido mais de 42 caracteres
```

Veja que o cURL envia os cabeçalhos, o servidor responde com 417 Expectation Failed, pois estamos enviando 45 bytes para um servidor que suporta no máximo 42, o cURL exibe a mensagem de log *HTTP error before end of send, stop sending* mostrando que ocorreu um erro antes de encerrar o envio e, por isso, encerra a comunicação, não enviando o corpo da requisição para o servidor.

> **Imagem 2**: Requisição inválida feita manualmente a partir do `telnet 127.0.0.1 5000` enviando o cabeçalho `Expect` a um servidor configurado para receber no máximo 5 bytes

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Leituras e referências**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/100
2. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.2.1
3. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3
4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect
5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/417
6. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1

Comment: Como fica o servidor? Poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: @Costamilam Resposta finalizada

Comment: Então se quisesse implementar no navegador teria que haver 2 pares de requisição/reposta?

Comment: @Costamilam Não e sim. Não, porque o navegador não suporta a comunicação com o `Expect` (na verdade não achei documentação que dissesse que suporta, então acho melhor considerar que não), o que faz impossível usar isso no navegador; sim, porque uma forma alternativa é justamente fazer duas requisições, utilizando o método OPTIONS ou fazendo uma requisição *normal*, passando os valores a serem validados através do corpo.