# Há vantagem em linguagens que empacotam (.dll, .class, .exe) para linguagens de script (.php, .py, .js)?

Tags: script, característica-linguagem, .exe

Há alguma vantagem em usar linguagens como o Java, .NET, C, C++ que geram um produto em que fica mais difícil de se alterar?

Por exemplo, se eu gero um `.class`, ou um `.jar`, haveria alguma vantagem em questão de segurança, privacidade, *copyrights*, de controle de código, ou de manutenção em relação ao uso de scripts em que o fonte fica aberto no servidor em produção?

Como é o caso do `.php`, ou `.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tudo tem vantagens e desvantagens, e muitos aspectos podem ser analisados, mas vou me focar na abordagem de segurança, que parece ser sua preocupação principal.

Deste ponto, sim há a vantagem de dificultar o acesso ao seu código fonte. Digo dificultar pois se procurar vais facilmente encontrar descompiladores para a maioria das linguagens, inclusive `.NET` e `Java`, que foram citadas.

Agora claro que é vantajoso compilar o código, do ponto de vista de segurança isso dá uma proteção a mais.

Vamos fazer uma analogia para pensar se vale o esforço: sua rede WiFi pode ser invadida, basta uma pessoa talentosa querer, agora, se elevar a dificuldade, usando um algoritmo de senha mais complexo, evitar senhas do tipo “123456”, colocar proteções adicionais, vais reduzir em muito a chance de sua rede ser invadida, não garante 100%, mas dificulta, é a mesma coisa com o código, melhor que um código todo aberto é um código compilado, alguém já vai precisar de um conhecimento a mais para fazer uma engenharia reversa.
E falando em segurança, podes além de compilar usar um *obfuscator*, que irá dificultar mais ainda essa tarefa.

Ainda assim é possível descompilar, especialmente em linguagens da plataforma `.NET` e `Java`, que são executadas sobre uma camada de *framework*, e por isso estão mais distantes de código nativo da máquina, o que facilita a engenharia reversa, além do código compilado conter metadados, que são mais dados para ajudar no processo de engenharia reversa.

Um código compilado em linguagem `C/C++` por exemplo é mais complexo para ser descompilado, para se fazer uma engenharia reversa, pois ele é compilado muito mais próximo da linguagem de máquina do computador.

Adicionalmente, o código compilado é executado mais rápido no computador pois não precisa ser interpretado em tempo de execução, mas em desvantagem precisa ser compilado contra a arquitetura da máquina que vai ser executado para tirar a máxima performance, enquanto o interpretado pode ser colocado e o interpretador faz isso.

Só como comentário adicional, compilar o código não protege efetivamente recursos como strings (textos, mensagens, etc) no seu código, que eventualmente podem até ser alterados sem descompilar o código, por isso se o ponto é segurança, salvar esses recursos em uma forma mais segura é uma boa prática (criptografar, serializar, mimificar, etc), o que pode inclusive ser feito com linguagens de script.

Comment: um código empacotado (com metadata) não seria uma garantia de que uma versão específica do fonte está implantada em produção, enquanto com script tal como php e js isso na prática se torna quase impossível de ser garantido?

Comment: isso não garante, mas diminui a chance de mudar a versão. quem fizer isso precisa ter o código fonte, alterar, compilar e colocar em produção, muito mais difícil do que alguém acessar o codigo no servidor, abrir num editor de texto qualquer e mudar, mas ainda assim não é 100% garantido. aliás, o acesso ao servidor deve ser bem controlado, independente do código que estive lá, mas sim, um código aberto em script é mais fácil de ser alterado pois o fonte está lá.

Answer (score 3):

Sim. E há desvantagens também, como em tudo.

Em questão de segurança não, pode ser ligeiramente mais difícil (mas em todos casos é possível acessar o código fonte, só não será um código tão legível, mas ainda extramente fácil para quem sabe quebrar a segurança.

Só para deixar bem claro, a suposta proteção é mínima, não é algo como fazer uma senha bem mais difícil de quebrar, para quem sabe fazer isso nem faz diferença a forma como está "protegido", ela perderá pouquíssimos minutos (quem sabe segundos) a mais em uma tarefa que levará dias para aproveitar o que conseguiu. E é possível ofuscar código em *scripts* de tal forma que pode ser tão difícil quanto outros meios de "proteger" o fonte (na verdade pode ser mais difícil porque você pode fazer um jeito personalizado que dificultaria um pouco mais quem for fazer isso já que ela teria que aprender como você ofuscou e não uma forma padronizada.

[Esta técnica tem nome](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46057/101) e pode até ser usada, mas não pode ser a única de segurança, ela é extremamente fraca. Importante ler essa [pergunta sobre proteger código fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/101).

Se está preocupado com alguém te roubar o código é claro que é mais fácil em *scripts*, ou seja, todos em JS são assim e, ao contrário do que as pessoas acham, isso não muda nada importante pra ela (as pessoas tem ilusões sobre roubo de código, isto só acontecerá se o código for muito bom, o que quase nunca é, e só será feito por alguém que nem saberá usar aquilo direito). Claro que se feito errado o fato de estar tudo fechado vai ajudar um tiquinho, se fizer certo não faz diferença.

Se a preocupação é que tem senhas, *tokens* ou outros dados que não podem ser divulgado, o problema já está aí, não pode ter essas informações no seu código. Sim, muita gente faz assim porque não ligam pra segurança, mas está errado.

Se a linguagem de *script* for usada para fazer *script* nada disso importa porque é algo que não produz nada tão relevante ou não tem nada que seja segredo. Se for usada para fazer aplicações tem tanta coisa errada nisso que este é o menor dos problemas.

Vamos diferenciar as linguagens de *script*. Veja a pergunta [Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101). Não é só sobre validação, tudo que está rodando em um *browser* não pode ser confiável, nem mesmo se ele não tiver um código de JS. Na verdade mesmo que só possa ser acessado externamente e não tenha uma HTML. Então se colocou alguma informação em JS que possa ser aproveitada para fazer algo errado já tem algo extremamente inseguro. O mesmo vale, só pra citar um exemplo, você ter um ERP no desktop de alguém cheio de códigos `.py`. Você ter código PHP pode não ser um problema tão grande. Se alguém invadir ou acessar naturalmente seu servidor será um problema se ela quiser pegar informações ali, mas sem essa entrada não tem um grande problema. Claro é uma exposição a mais.

Em termos de privacidade acho que não tem vantagem, nem sei se usou essa palavra de forma adequada (pode ser que usou porque coloca senhas no código, mas isso não é sobre privacidade, parece um assunto não relacionado. E os outros termos usados também não parecem tem a ver.

Manutenção não influencia, embora algumas pessoas possam achar mais fácil fazer gambiarras em linguagens de *script* abertas (existem linguagens de *scripts* que são ou podem ser encapsuladas em algum *container* e tem essa suposta "proteção"). Aí você decide se poder fazer gambiarras direto em produção ajuda ou atrapalha a manutenção. Eu tenho uma posição muito clara, mas algumas pessoas podem achar que um ganho mínimo de produtividade por não ter que compilar é importante (em geral a pessoa ignora o quanto aquilo teve que ser pensado, testado e passar por uma boa avaliação que consumiu muito mais tempo e que esse ganho de não precisar compilar é mínimo, só provoca percepção que foi mais rápido).

Ter tudo em um *container*, especialmente se ele pode ser executado pelo sistema operacional de forma direta, torna sua aplicação mais confiável (não é segura) afinal não tem um monte de arquivo que pode ser perdido ou manipulado acidentalmente. Tem outras vantagens que geralmente esse tipo de linguagem possui, mas parece que não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: container seria um Wildfly? ou um .exe gerado pelo compilador C?  Como ficaria mais confiável podendo ser executado diretamente pelo SO em relação a outro caso?

Comment: Qualquer coisa, mas penso mais em um executável. Fica mais confiável porque é uma coisa só, não várias partes que podem se perder

Comment: o fato de poder manipular o código acidentalmente não é um argumento forte para tornar uma linguagem de script de difícil rastreabilidade? por exemplo, ter a garantia de que o que está em produção realmente é a versão x?

Comment: Não faço ideia do que está falando sem detalhes.